# wait for scripts to load that have been added through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add jquery and then another script that relies on jquery.
I then need to have code that uses both assets but my problem is that i don't want my code to run until i know that both assets are loaded.

I think the process would be to load jquery and then wait until jquery is loaded by waiting for window.onload, then load the jquery plugin, then detect that the plugin has loaded, then load my own code that uses functions from the jquery plugin.

code so far:

```
// load jquery if it is not allready loaded and put it into no conflict mode so the $ is available for other librarys that might be allready on the page.
  if(!window.jQuery) {
     var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.type = "text/javascript";
     script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js";
     document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
     jQuery.noConflict(); // stop jquery eating the $
     console.log("added jquery");
  }

  window.onload = function(e) {  
    // we know that jquery should be available now as the window has loaded
    if ( !jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.serializeObject) ) {  // use jquery to ask if the plugins function is allready on the page (don't do this if the website already had the plugin)  
      // website didn't have the plugin so add it to the page. 
      var script = document.createElement('script');
       script.type = "text/javascript";
       script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-serialize-object/2.5.0/jquery.serialize-object.min.js";
       document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);     
    } 
    if ( !jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.serializeObject) ) {
     //    console.log("serializeObject is undefined");
// its going to be undefined here because Its still loading in the script     
    } else {
     //    console.log("we have serializeObject");
    }
    // I now dont know when to call my code that uses .serializeObject() because it could still be loading

    // my code
    var form_data_object = jQuery('form#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').serializeObject();
};
```

Comment: If jQuery loaded: [getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Comment: @user2129021 Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like

**Include**

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="AssetJS"></script>
```

**Script**

```
$("#AssetJS").attr("src", "Asset.js");

$("#AssetJS").load(function () {
   //after loaded jquery asset do your code here
})
```

Comment: does the <script type="text/javascript" id="AssetJS"></script> have to be in the markup to being with? I don't have access to the pages markup. I can only add my single script that adds the scripts for me.

Comment: so i need add a script to the head first using javascript that doesn't have a src attribute yet?

Comment: you are having `var script` only use that to check if `loaded` `jquery-serialize-object`

Comment: but I need to put jquery into noConflict mode as soon as it has loaded. but  .load() will not be available to check if the script that adds jquery has been loaded because I need jquery in the first place to use .load()

Comment: you can do this all by `.load()`

Comment: .load() is defined inside jquery so if i use .load() to detect if the jquery script has been added to the head it will error.

Comment: i was initially using window.onload = function(e) {jQuery.noConflict();} to make sure jquery had loaded but other library's could error if they use the $ before the window has loaded so i needed another way that would make noConflict() run as soon as jquery had been loaded. I have posted an answer myself after doing more research.

Answer (score 0):

OK i managed to find another way that is working for my specific needs so I am answering my own question.
Using this function from http://www.sitepoint.com/dynamically-load-jquery-library-javascript/

```
function loadScript(url, callback) {
var script = document.createElement("script")
script.type = "text/javascript";

if (script.readyState) { //IE
    script.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete") {
            script.onreadystatechange = null;
            callback();
        }
    };
} else { //Others
    script.onload = function () {
        callback();
    };
}

script.src = url;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

}

and usage in my case:

```
if(!window.jQuery) {
loadScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js", function () {
     jQuery.noConflict(); // stop jquery eating the $   
     console.log('jquery loaded');

    if ( !jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.serializeObject) ) {  // use jquery to ask if the plugins function is already on the page
        loadScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-serialize-object/2.5.0/jquery.serialize-object.min.js", function () {
             console.log('serialize loaded');
             SURGE_start(); // both scrips where not on the website but have now been added so lets run my code now.
        });
    }
});
} else {
if ( !jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.serializeObject) ) {  // use jquery to ask if the plugins function is already on the page
    loadScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-serialize-object/2.5.0/jquery.serialize-object.min.js", function () {
         console.log('serialize loaded');
         SURGE_start(); // jquery was on the web page but the plugin was not included. now we have both scripts lets run my code.
    });
} else {
    SURGE_start(); // web page already had both scripts so just run my code.
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

An easy way is using headjs. It's working fine on several projects.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).